# the final local variable qty price total cannot be assigned since it is defined in an enclosing type android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

Getting Error while calculating amount, three fields name, qty, price in which name and price getting from first activity and qty edittext thru this allowing user to input qty, but getting error :-
the final local variable qty, price, total cannot be assigned since it is defined in an enclosing type android.please see the source code

```
public class SecondScreenActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    final TextView txtCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCost);
    final EditText txtQty=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
    final double price = Double.parseDouble(txtCost.getText().toString());
    final double qty = Double.parseDouble(txtQty.getText().toString());
    final double total=0;


    Button btnClose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
    final TextView txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Receiving the Data
    String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    String cost = i.getStringExtra("cost");

    // Displaying Received data
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtCost.setText(cost);

    // Binding Click event to Button
    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //Closing SecondScreen Activity
            //finish();
        //Getting Error Here
               //the final local variable qty price total 
               //cannot be assigned since it is defined 
               //in an enclosing type android               
        qty=Double.parseDouble(txtQty.getText().toString());
        price=Double.parseDouble(txtCost.getText().toString());
        total=qty*price;
        txtResult.setText(Double.toString(total));


        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define the variables qty and price in the onCreate(). Only define them in your OnClickListener and all will be well. You can't change final variables after you set them. That's why they are final.